# RXJS 6 - toPromise

Tags: rxjs, angular6, es6-promise, angularfire2, rxjs6

Im currently trying to convert an `Observable` to a Promise. But when I call that method nothing happens. Im using Angular 6.

### Service

```
  public create(form: StoryForm): Promise<void | string> {
    const key: string = this.afStore.createId();

    return this.auth.authState.pipe(map(res =>
      <Story>{
        title: form.title, content: form.content, createdAt: new Date(), sid: key,
        uid: res.uid, username: res.displayName
      }
    )).toPromise().then((story: Story) =>
      this.afStore.doc(`stories/${key}`).set(story).catch(err => err.message));
  }
```

### Component

```
  public save() {
    this.triedToSave = true;
    if (this.storyForm.valid) {
      this.storyService.create(this.storyForm.value)
        .then(() => this.router.navigate(['/stories']))
        .catch((err: string) => this.notify.danger(err));
    }
  }
```

What save should do is to navigate or at least displaying the error.

### Auth

How authstate is implemented: It returns an observable of some user information. It is implemented in a different service and looks like this:

```
  public get authState(): Observable<firebase.User> {
    return this.afAuth.authState;
  }
```

### Edit

What confuses me is that, if I use a mock Object than it suddenly works:

```
  public create(form: StoryForm) {
    const key: string = this.afStore.createId();

    return of({uid: 'blubb', displayName: 'kdsjf', photoUrl: 'kjdfkjfd'}).pipe(map(user => {
      return {
        title: form.title, content: form.content, createdAt: new Date(), sid: key,
        uid: user.uid, username: user.displayName, photoUrl: user.photoURL
      } as Story;
    })).toPromise();
  }
```

But I wonder why toPromise does not work on the example above...

Comment: Are you sure you shouldn't have rather `map(res => ({ ... })` if you want to return an object?

Comment: I thought the curvy braces are only needed if you perform multiple actions within the map operator and then u need to specifically specify the return operator, meanwhile without curvy braces u dont have to specify return

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Im guessing that nothing happens because when you trigger the save method, nothing comes out of the authState. Apparently you expect that the authState observable or Subject will always trigger some output, which is only the case in specific cases.

The code below creates a -new- observable that listens to authState.

```
return this.auth.authState.pipe(map(res =>
      <Story>{
        title: form.title, content: form.content, createdAt: new Date(), sid: key,
        uid: res.uid, username: res.displayName
      }
    )).toPromise().then((story: Story) =>
      this.afStore.doc(`stories/${key}`).set(story).catch(err => err.message));
```

This code is only triggered by the save method though. My guess is that authState is either an observable, or a subject. You code would only work when the authState is passed a new value -after- the save method is triggered.

Your code that uses the mock object works, because you create an observable that immediately emits that one value.

If authState is a subject: replace it with a ReplaySubject(1)

If it is an observable, you need to publish is as a ReplaySubject like so:

```
authState.pipe(
    publishReplay(1),
    refCount()
);
```

To fully understand what is going on, read this article:
https://blog.mindorks.com/understanding-rxjava-subject-publish-replay-behavior-and-async-subject-224d663d452f

Its a java article, but the same principles apply.

But honestly, i cringe when i see people use the toPromise method :) 
You would learn rxjs much faster if you use it as intended!

If i would write this code, it would look kinda like this:

```
public save$: Subject<StoryForm> = Subject<StoryForm>();
private destroy$: Subject<any> = new Subject();

ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.destroy$.next();
}

onInit() {
    // the (click) eventhandler in your GUI should call save$.next(storyForm)
    // this will trigger this statement
    this.save$.pipe(
        // withLatestFrom will fetch the last value from an observable, 
        // it still needs to be a ReplaySubject or ReplaySubject for this to work though!
        // it will pass an array down the pipe with the storyForm value, and the last value from authState
        withLatestFrom(this.auth.authState),
        // switchMap does the actual work: note that we do not return a value, 
        // but an observable that should that return a value soon, that is why we need switchMap!
        switchMap(([storyForm, authInfo]) => {
            // i am assuming the "set" method returns an observable
            // if it returns a Promise, convert it using fromPromise
            return this.afStore.doc(`stories/${key}`).set(story).pipe(
                // catchError needs to be on your api call
                catchError(err => console.log(err))
            );
        }),
        // this will kill your subscriptino when the screen dies
        takeUntil(this.destroy$)
    ).subscribe(value => {
        // "value" will be the return value from the "set" call
        this.router.navigate(['/stories']);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the clearification. I guess I have to learn still a lot about observables. About your code-sample: Even though this approach might work it is like using a sledge-hammer to crack a nut. Why not use the simple approach of Promises to make one dummy http-call to the backend and get one response back. It is absolutely not necessary to make a stream based behaviour on this component to send one call to the backend, by clicking on a button. For that I guess Observables are offering not for nothing the toPromise() function.

Comment: About the sledge-hammer: i absolutely know what you mean. I felt the same way when i started learning reactive programming ... it looks like overkill. After a while though, you kinda make the switch and that sledgehammer starts looking like a compact leatherman ;) Still, for simple screens this approach does require more lines of code. In more complex screens however, its the other way around (especially when paired with a state store like redux)